# Page Refresh triggered by Server | Ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, server

A sensor creates data, transferred to a NodeJS web-server. Clients got an HTML/CSS/JavaScript interface with the displayed data.

Every time new data is received at the server, I want the server to inform all clients to refresh the page.

I googled a ton, but I mainly found solutions where the client repeatedly creates HTTP Requests, asking for changed data.
But I am looking for a solution, where the server triggers the HTTP Request by the client.

I found some articles about Ajax but couldn't find a great solution.

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Maybe you can use server-sent events? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events. This will make the server send a message to the client.

Comment: If you want to create an open channel communication between the client and the server you should check `Socketio`

Comment: Websockets or react is what you need.